# Azure Template Validation

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

This error is not helpful.  Is it possible to produce a validation error?  And furthermore, an ARM validation tool?  More specifically, an Azure CLI tool would be most helpful in addition to the below answer.

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 81d0e44d-0393-4f05-b9b9-4236f90c087f. {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group GasSchedulingApiTest-Linux. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group GasSchedulingApiTest-Linux. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "59324",
        "MessageTemplate": "Requested feature is not available in resource group {0}. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one.",
        "Parameters": [
          "GasSchedulingApiTest-Linux"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group GasSchedulingApiTest-Linux. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

Comment: you should raise this on the feedback site or on github, we cant help you with this here

Comment: Oh, I have, many times.  But SO seems to get more people's attention than the MS forums.  And this is a place most people start when trying to answer their questions.  So, I feel this is still an appropriate venue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Validate command from within a Visual Studio Resource Group project type or you can use the api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/validate

Comment: Let me check it out tomorrow, and if it works, I’ll gladly give ya the green check.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @TrevorBrooks!

Comment: I would still like a CLI tool, though, since there's a CLI tool for deployments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It could be this limitation:

> Based on a current limitation, for the same resource group you cannot
> mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

Or one of the limitations of creating function apps in existing resource groups:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Creating-Function-Apps-in-an-existing-Resource-Group